# Como funciona um e-CPF?

Tags: certificado-digital, openssl, assinatura-digital, smartdevice

Não possuo um Cartão nem o Token, mas gostaria de saber como funciona pois futuramente devo usar no sistema para gerar Laudos Médicos Certificados/Assinados Digitalmente.

Tenho algumas perguntas:

> -Consigo ele traz um conjunto de chave públicas e privadas ou devo gera-las apartir do Certificado?
>   -Ele é reconhecido como um dispositivo de armazenamento bloqueado?
>   -O sistema instala o certificado automaticamente?
>   -Consigo utilizar seu Certificado/Chave Privada/Chave Pública com o OpenSSL?

Desde já obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O e-CPF é mais ou menos a mesma coisa que o NF-e.

> -Consigo ele traz um conjunto de chave públicas e privadas ou devo gera-las apartir do Certificado?

Ele trás consigo mesmo. No certificado A3, as chaves ficam dentro do dispositivo USB, sendo acessada através da Certification Store do Windows.

> -Ele é reconhecido como um dispositivo de armazenamento bloqueado?

Depende do fabricante e do tipo de dispositivo (token, smartcard).

> -O sistema instala o certificado automaticamente?

Não. Depende do certificado e do SO. No Windows, o A3 é instalado automaticamente. O A3 depende do fabricante e da linguagem utilizada no desenvolvimento da sua aplicação. O A1 depende de instalação manual.

> -Consigo utilizar seu Certificado/Chave Privada/Chave Pública com o OpenSSL?

Sim.